# I can't get the postgres installation correctly

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-replication

I have spent quite a bit of time to install postgresql 11 on the high side production, but I just can't quite get it installation and configured correctly after I yum install

`rpm -i postgresl11-server-11.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64`
`rpm -i postgresl11-libs-11.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64`
`rpm -i rpm -i postgresl11-contrib-11.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64`

```
cd /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
```

the initializing database ...OK
according to the log file that all are ok and success and "You can now start the database server using /usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/11/data -l logfile start"

I can't run psql from postgres and from what I could see, the postgres directories seemed to be correctly excepted those missing features below under /usr/psql11/bin when I compared with the development server:
clusterdb, created, createuser, dropdb, dropuser, ecpg, pg_basebackup, pg_archivecleanup, pgbench, pg_config, pg_dump, pg_dumpall, pg_isready, pg_receivewal, pg_restore, pg_rewin, pg_test_fsync, pg_test_timing, pg_upgrade, pg_waldump, pgsql, reindexdb and vacuumdb.

Did I miss a step? Also, when I run `ps -ef|grep postgres`, the server running locally.

How do I get it install and run correctly?  I haven't install on the slave server yet.

Thanks for all your help.

Bach-Nga

Comment: There's a gap in your question between "initdb is successful" and "I can't run psql from postgres". What are the exact commands you run in between and what are the error messages you get if any?

Comment: I re-yum all the rpm and setup initdb.  All are working correctly now.  Thank you for all inputs